# use memoization in my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Been told to use memoization in my code not to call the function over and over. Is my implementation best way to use it? It seems redundant. Please advise how could I get rid of the initialize function.

```
class OrderService
  def initialize
    @current_orders = current_orders
  end

  def orders_acceptance
    @current_orders.
      with_statuses(:acceptance).
      select do |order|
        order.acceptance? if order.shopper_notified_at?
      end
  end

  def orders_start
    @current_orders.
      with_statuses(:start).
      select do |order|
        order.start?
      end
  end


  private

  def current_orders
    @current_orders ||= begin
      Order.includes(:timestamps).
        with_statuses(
          [
            :acceptance,
            :start
          ]
        )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Honestly I don't think this specific case provides much improvement, your method returns an active record relation, which I don't think is expensive to construct, don't get me wrong, the implementation is correct, but i don't think that it's very useful at this part.

Comment: What is `with_statuses`?

Comment: Head over here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

2 tips:

1. Don't call `current_orders` directly in constructor. Orders should be loaded for the first time when you're calling either `orders_start` or `orders_acceptance`. There is always a risk someone initializes this service early when request processing starts but because of some business rules neither of those methods is run. In that case - you called db but never consumed the result.
2. In both `orders_acceptance` and `orders_start` you're using `@current_orders` instance variable. It's ok but it's perfectly fine if you just call `current_orders` method multiple times - result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in the initializer.

The first time `current_orders` is called, the value will be memoized, which is "standard" memoiziation.

Also, as Mohammad pointed out, your method is returning an AR relation. The method should be:

```
@current_orders ||= Order.includes(:timestamps)
                         .with_statuses([:acceptance,:start])
                         .to_a
end
```

Also, why would you want to memoize this? `current_orders` should be current, not stale.